# AutoMapper map object to Lookup field in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, automapper, automapping, automapper-3

I am trying to map using AutoMapper.
Source object is C# object

```
public class Source
    {
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public Account Account{ get; set; }        
    }

public class Account
        {
            public string FirstName{ get; set; }
            public string LastName{ get; set; }
        }
```

My destination is a CRM entity named crm_destination which has fields like comment , Subject but it also has a **LookUp field** account of type **Account**.

**But I don't know how to map LookUp field.**

Following is my Automapper

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destinaetion>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.comment, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.comment))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.account, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.account));
```

**.ForMember(dest => dest.account, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.account))** is throwing error of type mismatch..

basically my problem is **I don't know how to map LookUp field  where CRM entity is destination.**

Answer (score 1):

Lookups are stored as EntityReferences in CRM.  So you'll need to convert your account to an EntityReference.

I have never used AutOMapper, but what Nicknow suggests makes sense.  Just call the `ToEntityReference()` method on Entity.

Comment: But can u please tell what changes do I have to do in the code (automapper)

Comment: How to Convert Object to an EntityReference ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [custom resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) in AutoMapper. In your custom resolver you'll need to query CRM to get the ID of the `account` record in that matches your `Account` object and return an EntityReference to this object.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it. Lookup creates a relationship. my lookp created a relationship name **cxrm_account_cxrm_source_account**
so instead of **.ForMember(dest => dest.account, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.account))**
I did

**.ForMember(dest => dest.cxrm_account_cxrm_source_account, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Account))**

now it is working

Comment: How do you get the `AccountID` for Dynamics CRM? Your `Account` object doesn't have a `Guid` but you need a `Guid`. The change above doesn't match to the code in your question, you need to edit something here.

Comment: I don't need to get Account ID. It generates a new record (Account) with new GUID. I need to get GUID only if I need to check whether record exists or not.

Comment: I don't know why you gave -1 to the answer but the above solution is working for me..